# send sql query to kinesis analytics by sdk or restful api?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

Any API allow to send SQL query from my server to kinesis analytics? I can not find related API in official SDK document.

Answer (score 0):

You specify a SQL statement when you create an application via the API.

See doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/dev/API_CreateApplication.html#API_CreateApplication_RequestSyntax

HTH